# Finding large databases of sphere packings

Tags: physical-chemistry, crystal-structure, reference-request

Part of my research is investigating sphere packings and their properties.I really would like a large database of sphere packings that I could investigate using a program I have written that tells me certain things about the packings. After doing some research I found some online databases but a lot of them haven't been taken care of so they're riddled with dead links.  I was wondering if anyone knows of any books or websites that have a lot of sphere packings that I could investigate.  Or if there is a way to interpret crystal structures as a sphere packing, seeing how there is a lot of crystal structure databases.

If anyone is confused as to what kind of data I'm looking I just need coordinates of the centers of spheres and their corresponding radii.  These need to form a packing where the spheres are touching like in this paper where the authors have found new bi-disperse packings.  Thanks!

http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/jp206115p

Comment: there are several open crystallographic databases with various liberty of access, but selecting and extracting sphere packings would be up to programmer.

Comment: That is exactly what I would like to do, permeakra! I guess I'm unsure as to how I would take one of these databases like, 
http://www.ccdc.cam.ac.uk/pages/Home.aspx
or
http://webmineral.com/
and begin extracting sphere packings?  Sorry for the late response I should have checked this sooner, thank you for your reply!

Comment: It is not clear what you want to do. Molecules are not spheres, so only crystallography database I would call "spherepacking" would be crystals of metals and simple salts. Of course, it is arguable how far they are spherical, too.

Comment: I think it's very clear from the post what I want to do, I want a database of sphere packings.  Nowhere in my post do I say that molecules are spheres or insinuate that.  Perhaps you meant to put this on my answer?  Either way, it's straight forward to interpret crystallography data as a sphere packing.  Take the Cartesian positions of the atoms and then take those positions for the center of spheres.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a partial answer to finding a large database of sphere packings, thanks to the comment from permeakra!

So far I have been obtaining .cif files from the large databases of crystal structures online such as, http://www.crystallography.net/.  Once I have the .cif files I use openbabel to convert those files to .xyz files.  From here I have a table that describes a crystal's structure by the x,y, and z coordinates of each particular element for example,

\begin{array}{c|c c c}
\ce{Mg}      &   1.01054     &   1.01054   &     1.01054\\\hline
\ce{Al}      &   1.01054     & 1.01054     &   1.01054\\\hline
\ce{Al}      &   4.04217     &   4.04217   &     4.04217\\\hline
\ce{Mg}      &   4.04217     &   4.04217    &    4.04217\\\hline
\ce{O}       &   2.11390     &   2.11390    & 2.11390
\end{array}

But my problem from here is that babel has failed to return the ionic radius which I suppose can be retrieved online via wikipedia or something.  I posted another question that is more specific to .cif files which expands on this problem which can be found here, [Extracting "Crystal Radii" from a CIF file](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/34114/extracting-crystal-radii-from-a-cif-file%5C).\

Limitations to this approach include that I can only find 3D sphere packings and it's a rather long and clunky procedure for obtaining lots of sphere packings.

Comment: It's not clear to me what kind of radius you want - certainly Open Babel has van der Waals and covalent radii as I indicated in the other question.